# Cursor in Stored Procedure Performance Issues

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

I found a cursor being used in the below SQL and dynamic SQL.  Profile brings up quite a bit of execution plans and I think it has to deal with this cursor.  Is this a bad choice of SQL?

```
SET @SelectStmtSubHeader = 'SELECT DISTINCT
        dbo.dsb_testID(sh.GPCustomerID) AScursor -- RIGHT HERE
         PONumber,
        sh.GPCustomerID,
        .....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not an example of a cursor.

A cursor needs to be...

```
DECLARE this_is_a_cursor CURSOR
FOR
  SELECT
    stuff
  FROM
    a_query
```

The snipped code you've shown appears to use a scalar function to derive a value, which it aliases to the word `cursor`.  But having a field called `cursor` doesn't make it a cursor.

Comment: +1 from me for figuring out it wasn't a cursor lol.  I answered the question and you proved the question moot :p

Answer (score 3):

Cursors are nearly always a bad choice to be avoided if alternatives exist in set logic.

SQL is based around set logic.  They aren't meant to be iterated through like a collection.

The SQL Optimizers are usually pretty good at finding clever ways to retrieve your data.  A cursor is a relatively unsophisticated tool.  ANSI SQL does require it though, so it's usually present.

Here is a good example from Sybase

[Cursor Performance Example](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/ptallbk/@ebt-link;pt=44283?target=%25N%15_44807_START_RESTART_N%25)

Comment: Absolutist statements like that make me shiver.  CURSORs always have a performance overhead, but there are scenarios where the overhead is less than the alternative.  Try running totals in SQL for example.  *Just because they're often inappropriately used by naive programmers, it doesn't make them universally bad.*

Comment: Fair enough.  Mind you though the link I gave came from Sybase. Being a maker of DBs I'd imagine they're a good source and they basically said if you have an alternative use it.  That being said I'll edit my post ;)